# @azure/cosmos.js - get database synchronously

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using node.js SDK - @azure/cosmos.js to retrieve a database synchronously. The documentation on usage of SDK(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos/v/2.0.0-3) -

```
const database = await client.database(databaseId);
```

await can only be used in async methods. How can I retrieve database in synchronous method?

Comment: `async` / `await` is as good as a sync operation - what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Cosmos SDK dev lead here.

There are no sync APIs in @azure/cosmos. @azure/cosmos relies on apis that are async only such as https.request. While there are libraries that can farm those APIs out to a child worker while blocking, they are not commonly used and we don't have plans to support it.

As James recommended, take a look at using the `await` syntax which makes it read like sync code without fighting the way Node.js wants to do I/O work.

```
async function main() {
    const db = await client.databases.create("foo");
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

You can also look at the Python SDK which has a sync API (for now ).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I wrapped the call in an async method and made the method return a Promise.